# Prove or Disprove .

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$\vDash \forall x (\alpha \lor \beta) \implies (  \forall x \alpha \lor \forall x \beta) $.

I am not able to start this question, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have $x$ as a free variable?

Comment: No they are bounded variables.

Comment: They’re bound in $\forall x(\alpha\lor\beta)$ and in $\forall x\alpha\lor\forall x\beta$, but I’m asking about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ themselves. In other words, can $\alpha$ be something like ‘$x=3$’?

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depends on x, all this I know, please help

Comment: **Hint:** If we try and disprove this, then we need to find a countermodel. Can you think of any model with two unary predicates $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Does this model satisfy this condition?

Comment: @Shubham: Okay, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend on $x$, then $x$ is free in $\alpha$ and $\beta$, as I suspected.

Comment: "I only know that I know nothing" : what does mean the symbol $\vDash$, please?

Comment: $\models$ is "models", written as \models. $M\models\varphi$ means $\varphi$ is true in the model $M$. With no specific model, $\models\varphi$ means $\varphi$ is true in *all* models, it's *valid*, which by the completeness theorem is the same thing as *provable* (in any of the many deductive systems for first-order logic, e.g. natural deduction, Hilbert-style axiomatic systems, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha(x)$ is true of some $x$ and false of others in some model, then taking $\beta(x) = \neg\alpha(x)$ gives a counterexample: a model in which the sentence is false.

For example, let $\alpha(x)$ be $x=1$ and $\beta(x) = \neg\alpha(x) = x\ne 1$. Of course it's true that
$$
\forall x\,(x=1 \lor x\ne 1).
$$ 
(The sentence is *valid*). But it's not valid that
$$
\forall x\, x=1 \lor \forall x\, x\ne 1,
$$
because in, say, the integers, or in any model with more than one element, not every $x$ is equal to $1$, and not every $x$ is unequal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The statement *Every integer is even or odd* is an instance of $\forall x(\alpha\lor\beta)$.

Comment: Yes I get a bit of it but can you please explain how to formally prove this using valuations.

Comment: What you say is it not valid or a valid?

Comment: @Shubham: I associate *valuations* with propositional logic; here you’re dealing with predicate logic, so you’d be working *interpretations*, at least in the terminology with which I’m familiar. What exactly do you mean by a valuation?

Comment: @Shubham: If you think about the example in my hint, you should be able to decide whether it’s valid or not. What would $\forall x\alpha$ be in terms of that example? What about $\forall x\beta$?